# Azure Search: price range - min & max value calculation

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net, azure-cognitive-search

Currently, I am trying out Azure Search SDK. Having a strong background working with [lucene](https://lucenenet.apache.org/) and [bobobrowse](https://github.com/NightOwl888/BoboBrowse.Net), the Azure Search is quite fantastic and has a lot of features from both frameworks out of the box.

The only thing I am puzzling with is to get the minimum and maximum value of a numeric facet item. By intention, I do not want to use the [interval parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-faceted-navigation) nor the [value lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-faceted-navigation):

[image: Azure Facet Navigation]

My requirement is to display the price facet with a calculated minimum and maximum value. Following website has such a facet in their facet list:

[image: Price Range]

In my existing desktop application (.Net) I successfully used [BoboBrowse](https://github.com/NightOwl888/BoboBrowse.Net) framework and implemented a [Custom-FacetHandler](https://github.com/NightOwl888/BoboBrowse.Net/wiki/Prebuilt-Facet-Handler-Types) to get the desired results which are shown in the following picture below:

[image: MultiValue Facet Handler Result]

Never mind the facet values within these pictures. These are just length, height and other characteristic values of tools.

This is how I build one document for demonstration purposes. There is a price field which is generated dynamically. Because of azure search needs a strongly fixed schema for every index. I update the schema within the indexing process. This works very well.

[image: Price Field]

So the question is how can i achieve the required functionality with azure search?

In the elastic search, such a problem could be solved by using [Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html). Does this feature exist in Azure Search?

Comment: While I don't have an answer for you, I can tell you that Aggregations are not supported in Azure Search. See here (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/8382225-add-aggregations-functionality)

Answer (score 1):

The `$filter` parameter supports the `lt` (less than) and `gt` (greater than) operators. For example: `$filter=price gt 0 and price lt < 100`

Sample code:

```
string PriceFilter(double? fromPrice, double? toPrice)
{
   var filter = "$filter=";
   if(fromPrice.HasValue) 
          filter+="price gt " + fromPrice.Value.ToString() 
                + (toPrice.HasValue ? " and " : "");
   if(toPrice.HasValue) 
          filter+="price lt " + toPrice.Value.ToString();
   return filter;
}
```

Reference: *[Build a filter for a range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-faceted-navigation#build-a-filter-for-a-range)*

Comment: Only for the filtering operation this is correct but i am looking for a way to get the minimum and maximun values when requesting the actual range facets